# Scss modify rules based on topmost parent

Tags: sass

Let's propose that we have the following scss code:

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c {
            // rules here
        }
     }
}
```

This will output the following css: `.a .b .c`

Now, if I would like to modify the ruleset of `.c` if `.a` gets another class, I would have to modify my scss like this:

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c {
            // rules here
        }
     }

     &.d {
        .b {
            .c {
              // rules here
            }
        }
     }
}
```

If there are multiple modifications, my scss will become very long, and the rules refering to `.c` will be out and apart. Isn't there an easier syntax, to keep all the rules of `.c` together in the code, so that when I need to modify something, it will be easier? I am thinking about something along these lines:

```
.a {
    .b {
        .c {
            // rules here

            ^^&.d {
               // go up 2 selectors (hence twicte the ^), and add to the selector the `.d` class, then keep on modifying the current selector `.c` here
            }
        }
     }
}
```

**EDIT:** I am used to specify each element (or most, any case), in the selector path, so my selectors are as explicit as possible. The above example can be reflected for a dashboard button, which is deep inside the dashboard, and with the basic approach, I will have to replicate 5 levels of nesting, to specify some style for a button, based on the status of the dashboard (ie. sidebar-open). I could of course add a class directly to the button and style it like that, but imo that's an overkill, as there are a lot of different things that change in the stylesheet for this specific status.

For a complete example, when I click this specific button, the sidebar should pop out, some other elements that are getting overlapped, should be pushed to the right, etc. My javascript, simply adds the status representing class to the whole dashboard, and I would like to style everything accordingly. But this way, the styles for the different elements are far and apart unfortunately.

Comment: I would like to note that this looks like a very bad practice which will lead to very unmaintainable code which will easily break and be very hard to understand. Is there any reason why you can't set specific classes and use some sort of if cases to assign different classes in HTML and then style without nesting more than 1 level?

Comment: @MiroslavSaracevic added an edit to the original post, to try to explain why I am trying to go forward with this approach. Basically, I want to deviate anything that is possible away from javascript, and achieve a plain css solution for things that are possible this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

- [sass variable](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) to structure your nested classes and styles.
- [@each rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) to iterate over every key/value pair to emit styles.

Let's suppose you can have 3 classes on first level i.e `x, y, z`, with their child classes `a`, `b`.

> Then your scss `variable` code will look like below:

```css
$classes: (
 x: (
   a: (
      color: blue,
      font-size: 15px
     ),
   b: (
      color: blue,
      font-weight: 600
   )
 ),
 y: (
   a: (
      color: red,
     ),
   b: (
      color: blue,
      font-size:20px
   )
 ),
z: (
  a: (
      color: black,
      overflow: scroll
     ),
   b: (
      color: black,
      font-size: 20px,
      background-color: white
   )
 )
);
```

> Now we can iterate above variable like below:

```js
@each $key, $value in $classes {
 .#{$key} {
   @each $key1, $value1 in $value {
     .#{$key1} {
       @each $key2, $value2 in $value1 {
          #{$key2}: $value2
       }
      }
   }
 }
}
```

If in case you want to add more classes in the future, then you need follow the same structure and add class names and styles accordingly.

### Result (CSS)

```css
.x .a {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.x .b {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.y .a {
  color: red;
}
.y .b {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.z .a {
  color: black;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.z .b {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I hope it solves your problem & beautifies your code as well.

Comment: a simple `@each` won't do here, as I want to add different rules for the element, based on the topmost parent.

Comment: You can add data in key, value pair as well in $classes variable.. Updating code...\

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I've updated the answer, please check.